# How do I have my UIView use my custom CALayer as its backing layer?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am overriding UIView's layerClass method as recommended in apple's documentation like this:

```
+ (Class)layerClass {
     return [ViewLayerBase class];
}
```

In my viewLayerBase custom class I have an init Method implemented like this:

```
- (id)initWithRect:(CGRect)rect {
     if ((self = [super init])) {
         NSLog(@"I got called");
     }
     return self;
}
```

This method is clearly not being called by my UIView subclass.  Given that the layer property of UIView is read-only and I cannot do `myView.layer = [ViewLayerBase alloc] initWithRect...` how do I get UIView to instantiate my custom CALayer subclass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it right (adding a `layerClass` class method to your custom UIView class.)

The problem is your init method. For CALayer, the designated init method is init, not initWithRect. Try moving your code to `-init`. That should work.

Comment: That works.  However, what if I wish my Layer Init method to have the same bounds as my view?

Comment: That is what happens automatically.  When you set attributes on the view like bounds, it is really just a passthrough to setting them on the layer.